Communication between ROS 2 nodes operating on different networks with NAT restrictions
How would you manage communication between ROS 2 nodes operating on different networks with NAT restrictions, ensuring low latency and compatibility with the DDS middleware while retaining the automatic discovery capabilities provided by ROS 2?
Managing communication in ROS 2 across networks with NAT restrictions, ensuring low latency, DDS compatibility, and automatic discovery.
